# polymorphicなopen recursionを作りたい

Tags: ocaml

OCaml 4.02で導入されたExtensible variant typesを使ってexpression problemの解のようなものを書いていた際、polymorphicなopen recursionが欲しくなりましたが、書けなくて困っています。

```
module Lang = struct
  type 'a expr = ..
  type 'a expr +=
      Num : int -> int expr
    | App : ('a -> 'b) expr * 'a expr -> 'b expr

  type reval = { f : 'a. 'a expr -> 'a }

  (* open recursion. polymorphicなlet recだと拡張できないので。 *)
  (* evalをレコードにしてあるのは、Appのeval適用で型が異なる適用を二回行うので、forallを付ける必要があったから。 *)
  let open_eval (type a) (eval:reval) (exp:a expr) : a =
    match exp with
      Num i -> i
    | App (f, x) -> eval.f f (eval.f x)
    | _ -> failwith "no match"
end

(* Langのデータと関数の両方の拡張. *)
module Plus = struct
  type 'a Lang.expr += 
      Plus : (int -> int -> int) Lang.expr

  let open_eval (type a) (eval:Lang.reval) (expr:a Lang.expr) : a = 
    match expr with
      Plus -> (+)
    | x -> Lang.open_eval eval x

  let show : type a. a Lang.expr -> string = function
      Plus -> "plus"
    | Lang.App _ -> "app"
    | Lang.Num _ -> "num"
    | _ -> "no match"
end
```

ここまではコンパイル通ります。しかし、その後不動点演算子fixによって`fix Plus.open_eval`したいのですが、fixの実装はどうやって書けばいいのでしょうか？
通常の不動点演算子は下記の記事のようにかけるのは知っています。
http://d.hatena.ne.jp/KeisukeNakano/20060926/1159273362
そもそも書けないのかもしれませんが、ご助言ありましたら宜しくお願い申し上げます。

**追記**
ちなみに、

```
let fix (`M x) y = y Lang.{ f = fun z -> x (`M x) y z }
```

だと
Error: This field value has type 'b Lang.expr -> 'b which is less general than 'a. 'a Lang.expr -> 'a
のようにfix定義時にエラーになります。orz

Answer (score 3):

まず、特にこだわらずに不動点を取ってみます。

```
open Lang

let rec fixed =
  fun x -> Plus.open_eval { f = fixed }  x
```

これはエラーです。

```
File "xxx", line 40, characters 36-41:
Error: This field value has type 'b Lang.expr -> 'b
       which is less general than 'a. 'a Lang.expr -> 'a
```

理由は ML では `let` で定義されている値、ここでは `fixed`、 `let` の内側では多相的な型を取れず、多相フィールド `{ f = .. }` に突っ込めないからです。ご質問の追記と同じ状態です。

内部で `fixed` に多相的な型を持たせるには、`fixed` の多相型を明示して polymorphic recursion を使えばよいです:

```
open Lang
open Plus

let rec fixed : 'a . 'a expr -> 'a = (* <= これがミソ *)
  fun x -> Plus.open_eval { f = fixed }  x  (* 内部でも fixed は多相型を持つので reval に突っ込める *)

let () =
  print_int @@ fixed
    (App 
       (App (Plus, (App (App (Plus, Num 21), Num 21))),
        App (App (Plus, Num 21), Num 21)))
```

`84` が出力されます。

所謂不動点演算子

```
let rec fix f x = f (fix f) x
```

に突っ込むには `open_eval` を `('a eval -> 'a) -> 'a eval -> 'a` という値に変えなければいけませんが、

```
let open_eval' = fun f x -> Plus.open_eval {f = f} x   (* うまくいかない… *)
```

これは `open_eval' : 'a. ('b . 'b expr -> 'b) -> 'a expr` のような型が欲しいのですが、これが書ければもともと多相レコードフィールによる高rank多相エンコードは必要ないわけですから、無理っぽいかなあと思います。

Polymorphic な open recursion を作りたい、という質問のタイトルを実現するならば `fix` はあきらめてもいいんじゃないかと思います…

Comment: ありがとうございます。thisによる遅延バインディグで実質open recursionがデフォルトで使えるクラスベースオブジェクト指向の言語機能はすごいと思いました。

Answer (score 2):

普通の fix が使えなくても、open_eval専用の fix が定義できますよ。

```
let open_eval_wrap eval = {f = fun x -> open_eval eval x}

let rec eval_fix (evalf : reval -> reval) : reval =
  {f = fun x -> (evalf (eval_fix evalf)).f x}

let eval x = (eval_fix open_eval_wrap).f x
```

それで答えになりますか？

また、邪魔しているのは関数型というcamlspotterのコメントに注目して、lazy を使った不動点という手もあります。こちらは完全に一般的な形になります。

```
let rec lazy_fix (f : 'a Lazy.t -> 'a) =
  lazy (f (lazy_fix f))
```

定義を少し変える必要があります。

```
module Lang = struct
  type 'a expr = ..
  type 'a expr +=
      Num : int -> int expr
    | App : ('a -> 'b) expr * 'a expr -> 'b expr
    | Succ : (int -> int) expr

  type reval = { f : 'a. 'a expr -> 'a }
  let run (eval : reval Lazy.t) = (Lazy.force eval).f

  let open_eval (type a) eval (exp:a expr) : a =
    match exp with
      Num i -> i
    | App (f, x) -> run eval f (run eval x)
    | Succ -> succ
    | _ -> failwith "no match"

  let open_eval_wrap eval = {f = fun x -> open_eval eval x}
end
```

そうすると、不動点の閉じ方はこれで済みます。

```
let eval x = Lang.run (lazy_fix Plus.open_eval_wrap) x
```

Comment: 型変数が `reval` に隠蔽されているので多相性の問題は回避できているのですね。ただ `reval` はもはや関数型を持たないので普通の `fix` は使えない、と、そんな感じでしょうか

Comment: そうですね。forall 'a. 'a expr -> 'a の forall がどうしても外に必要なので、関数型になりません。そしてコア言語に高階多相性がないので、forall 'a を含めたものは一般化できません。

Answer (score 1):

因みに、OCamlにはファンクターという高階多相性機構があるので、camlspotterの解答もそれを使って一般化できます。

```
module type Lang = sig
  type 'a expr
  type reval = { f : 'a. 'a expr -> 'a }
  val open_eval : reval -> 'a expr -> 'a
end

module Fix (L : Lang) = struct
  let rec eval : 'a. 'a L.expr -> 'a =
    fun x -> L.open_eval {L.f = eval} x
end

module Plus' = Fix (struct include Lang include Plus end)
```

前の解答に比べてのメリットは、この Lang.expr だけではなく、任意の eval 関数を持った型に対して使えることです。

Comment: なるほど、これなら他の言語を作った時でも使えそうです。ファンクターえらい。